# HTML page not rendering from Flask after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I want to send a JavaScript variable with a image that a user will upload to my Flask file where processing will be done. So I am using Formdata and a AJAX call for the same. But after the data and image is received in flask and processing is done, I am unable to render a HTML page in flask which will display the processed image .

Java Script Code :

```
formdata = new FormData();      
jQuery("#image_to_upload").on("change", function() {     // On Change Of image upload
    var file = this.files[0];
    if (formdata) {
        formdata.append("file", file);
        formdata.append("array", filtersActive);
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "/object-detect-uploader",   
            type: "POST",
            data: formdata,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success:function(){}
        });
    }                       
});
```

Flask Code :

```
@app.route("/object-detect-uploader", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_object_detection():
    detect_objs = request.values['array'].split(",")

    d_array= [0 for i in range(6) ]
    for i in detect_objs:
        d_array[int(i)] = 1
    for upload in request.files.getlist("file"):
        filename = upload.filename
        # This is to verify files are supported
        ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
        if (ext == ".jpg") or (ext == ".png"): #File extention check
            print("File supported moving on...")
            ans=(object_detection_module.object_detection(upload,d_array))
        else:
            render_template("Error.html", message="Files uploaded are not supported...")
    print("Rendering")
    return render_template("index.html", result = ans)
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <br>
    <br>
<h1><center>Output</h1></center>
<br> 
<img src="data:image/png;base64,  {{result[0]}}" >
<br>
<br>
<h2> No of objects = {{ result[1] }}</h2> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your index.html template code?

Comment: @MihirDass added the index.html code.

Answer (score 0):

An Ajax call is an asynchronous request initiated by the browser that **does not reload the page** when it receives the server response.

IMO, since you want to render the template, you should not use AJAX, just use a normal `<form>` element or create a form programmatically, fill the data, then submit with `jQuery('selector').submit()`.